# Manipulate[] does not function when using `Prolog->Inset`

Tags: graphics, manipulate

I want to slide the blue point with `Manipulate[]`. However, the following code does not function:

```
Manipulate[
     Plot[{0, 0}, {x, 500, 1000}, 
         Prolog -> Inset[Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[{nonTime, 0}]}]]], 
     {nonTime, 500, 1000}]
```

But, below code does work:

```
plt = Plot[{0, 0}, {x, 500, 1000}];
Manipulate[
    Show[{plt, Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[{nonTime, 0}]}]}], 
    {nonTime, 500, 1000}]
```

I wonder why the first piece code does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inset >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Inset.html)

- Inset[obj] *is equivalent to* Inset[obj,Center].

Since you don't use the second argument of `Inset` to specify the position, the `Graphics` object is placed at the center of the enclosing graphic.

So you can use `{nonTime, 0}` as the second argument in `Inset` to have the point dynamically move with the slider:

```
Manipulate[Plot[{0, 0}, {x, 500, 1000}, 
  Prolog -> Inset[Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[{0, 0}]}], 
   {nonTime, 0}]], 
 {nonTime, 500, 1000}]
```

[image]

If you don't have to use `Inset` a simpler alternative that gives the same result is to use

```
Prolog -> {PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[{nonTime, 0}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without Prolog&Inset you can use Show:

```
Manipulate[
Show[{Plot[{0, 0}, {x, 500, 1000}], 
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[{nonTime, 0}]}]
}], {nonTime, 500, 1000}]
```